# Python timetable pass start and finish time that pressed button relevant to position

Tags: python, loops, object, button, tkinter

For my coursework i am making a booking system and i have been messing around trying to make a page which shows current week lessons and when the button is clicked it comes up with that students details on a separate page.But i don't know how to go about passing that time into my open page sub(which writes a txt file which is going to be used for SQL to get the students details). The current way i have done it just passes the max times into the sub.

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Initialize the frame. """
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)  
        self.grid()
        self.timetable_button_gen_weekdays()
        self.timetable_button_gen_weekends()


    def timetable_button_gen_weekdays(self):
        c = datetime.datetime(100,1,1,16,00,00)
        self.Monday_lbl = Label(self, text = "Monday")
        self.Monday_lbl.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.Tuesday_lbl = Label(self, text = "Tuesday")
        self.Tuesday_lbl.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        self.Wednesday_lbl = Label(self, text = "Wednesday")
        self.Wednesday_lbl.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        self.Thursday_lbl = Label(self, text = "Thursday")
        self.Thursday_lbl.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
        self.Friday_lbl = Label(self, text = "Friday")
        self.Friday_lbl.grid(row = 5, column = 0)
        for k in range(8):
            b = c + datetime.timedelta(minutes = (30 * k))
            d = b + datetime.timedelta(minutes = (30))
            self.i_time_weekdays_lbl = Label(self, text = b.time().strftime('%H:%M')+" to "+d.time().strftime('%H:%M'))
            self.i_time_weekdays_lbl.grid(row = 0, column = k + 1)
        for i in range(5):
            for a in range(8):
                b = c + datetime.timedelta(minutes = (30 * a))
                d = b + datetime.timedelta(minutes = (30))
                bttn_i_a = Button(self, text = "available",command = lambda: self.OpenPage(b.time().strftime('%H:%M'),d.time().strftime('%H:%M')))
                bttn_i_a.grid(row = i + 1, column = a + 1)
                bttn_i_a.config(height = 2, width = 10)

    def timetable_button_gen_weekends(self):
        c = datetime.datetime(100,1,1,10,00,00)
        self.Saturday_lbl = Label(self, text = "Saturday")
        self.Saturday_lbl.grid(row = 8, column = 0)
        self.Sunday_lbl = Label(self, text = "Sunday")
        self.Sunday_lbl.grid(row = 9, column = 0)
        self.weekend_lbl = Label(self, text = "Weekend")
        self.weekend_lbl.grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = W)
        for k in range(10):
            b = c + datetime.timedelta(minutes = (30 * k))
            d = b + datetime.timedelta(minutes = (30))
            self.i_time_weekdays_lbl = Label(self, text = b.time().strftime('%H:%M')+" to "+d.time().strftime('%H:%M'))
            self.i_time_weekdays_lbl.grid(row = 7, column = k + 1)
        for i in range(2):
            for a in range(10):
                b = c + datetime.timedelta(minutes = (30 * a))
                d = b + datetime.timedelta(minutes = (30))
                bttn_i_a = Button(self, text = "available",command = lambda: self.OpenPage(b.time().strftime('%H:%M'),d.time().strftime('%H:%M')))
                bttn_i_a.grid(row = i + 8, column = a + 1)
                bttn_i_a.config(height = 2, width = 10)

    def OpenPage(self,startime,finishtime):
        file = open("PassTimes.txt","w")
        file.write(startime)
        file.write("\n")
        file.write(finishtime)
        print(startime)
        print(finishtime)
        filepath = "PresentStudent.py"

        global_namespace = {"__file__": filepath, "__name__": "__main__"}
        with open(filepath, 'rb') as file:
            exec(compile(file.read(), filepath, 'exec'), global_namespace)


root = Tk()
root.title("test")
root.geometry("2000x2000")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/).

**General**

IMHO, running the main routine of "PresentStudent.py" does not look that clean.
It works, but a main routine is built for when the script is called directly, not when it is imported and used in some other script.

Are you aware of the [modules functionality](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) in python?

I would recommend creating a function in `PresentStudent.py` that does what you are doing inside your main routine. Give the function parameters to pass the `.txt-Filename`.

e.g.

`def presentStudentCall(inputFile):`

and use it inside your script like:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    # here we import PresentStudent.py, as we import it __main__ will not run
    import PresentStudent

    #[...]

    def OpenPage(self, stime, etime):
        #[...]
        # Instead of executing a file we call the function from the module
        PresentStudent.presentStudentCall(file)
```

If you want to display the data inside a second frame, you could also declare a class in `PresentStudent.py` and use it like:

```
def OpenPage(self, stime, etime):
    #[...]
    student=PresentStudent.Student() # assuming to name the class "Student"
    student.presentStudentCall(file)
```

**Your question itself**

using the lambda does not need to be the best way. In matters of [scope and garbage collecting](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html) your code only passes the last generated "b"s and "c"s to the definition.

What you could do to make it work is calculating the sender item in `OpenPage`:

To achieve that, I recommend having arrays for your time spans storing starting times.
Like

```
c = datetime.datetime(100,1,1,16,00,00)    
self.weektimes    = ["%s"%(c+datetime.timedelta(minutes=30*k)) for k in range(8)]
self.weekendtimes = ["%s"%((c+datetime.timedelta(minutes=30*k)) for k in range(10)]
```

First you need to bind the click event to the widget(in that case your button)
`bttn_i_a.bind("<Button-1>", self.OnPage)`
Your OpenPage could then look like this:

```
def OpenPage(self, event):
    import time
    # With that, we get the row and column where we clicked in
    grid_info=event.widget.grid_info()

    # week or weekend?
    if grid_info["row"] > 5: #may depend on amount of headers
        _timearray=self.weekendtimes
    else:
        _timearray=self.weektimes

    # get the column
    col=grid_info["column"]

    # get the startTime
    stime=_timearray[col]

    # end time is +30 minutes
    etime="%s"%(time.strptime("%s"%stime, "%H:%M")+time.struct_time(tm_min=30))

    # now call the handler...
```

Comment: Thanks very  much i was thinking of using its grid position but i couldn't find how to  I obviously didn't look hard enough. Also thank you for all the other advice i wasn't particularly keen on asking my teacher as i didn't want to look dumb so i asked on here. Sorry for all the trouble.